# Excel VBA Insert Column with standard name + number

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub AddAdjustment()
'
' AddAdjustment Macro
'

Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("D:D").Select
With Range("D13").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Adjustment 1"
Range("D13").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
    Range("D18").Select
End Sub
```

I have a worksheet where I want to insert a column with the name "Adjustment #" at the top of the column. Each time I run the macro I want it to be Adjustment 1, Adjustment 2, Adjustment 3, etc....

How would this be possible? I can insert the columns but I cannot figure out how to make the name advance in number every time. Thanks!

Comment: "*Each time I run the macro*"  What macro?  More information is needed for this to be a well-posed question.

Comment: I'm inserting a new column each time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on your question and provided code - here is the possible solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddAdjustment()
Static colNo As Long

colNo = colNo + 1

Cells(1, 4).EntireColumn.Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

With Cells(13, 4)
    .Value = "Adjustment " & colNo
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

    Cells(18, 4).Select

End Sub
```